# How to Display content of Form when Submit is clicked

Tags: html

I have created a form to accept registration of users.  What I want is to make the content of the form show in another page when the submit button is clicked - so that the user can view the details of the form and print.

```
    <form action="sendresult.php" method="post" name="form2" id="form2" autocomplete="on">
      <p align="center"><img src="images/headerform.jpg" width="691" height="135"></p>
      <p align="center"><strong style="font-size: 24px;">COURSE REGISTRATION FORM
      </strong><a href="pageone.html"> - <span style="color: #00F"><strong><em>Click Here to Return to other pages</em></strong></span></a></p>
      <p align="center" style="text-align: left; font-size: 16px;">
        <label for="LastName">LAST NAME:</label>
        <input name="LastName" type="text" id="LastName" form="form2" size="40">
        <label for="Firstname">FIRST NAME:</label>
        <input name="Firstname" type="text" id="Firstname" form="form2" size="40">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Occupation">OCCUPATION:</label>
        <input name="Occupation" type="text" id="Occupation" form="form2" size="100" maxlength="40">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Organisation">ORGANISATION:</label>
        <input name="Organisation" type="text" id="Organisation" form="form2" size="97">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Address">ADDRESS:</label>
        <input name="Address" type="text" id="Address" form="form2" size="105">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="email:">EMAIL:</label>
        <input name="email:" type="email" id="email:" form="form2" size="109">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="Telephone">TELEPHONE:</label>
        <input name="Telephone" type="tel" id="Telephone" form="form2" size="102">
      </p>
      <u><p><strong>PAYMENT MODE</strong></p></u>
      <u><p><strong><span style="color: #F00">Bank Account Details </span></strong></p></u>
      <p><strong><span style="color: #F00">Bank - Zenith Bank Nig Plc.</span></strong></p>
      <p><strong><span style="color: #F00">Account Name:- Lead Vision Concepts</span></strong></p>
      <p><strong><span style="color: #F00">Account Number:- </span></strong></p>
      <table width="200">
        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input name="Bank" type="radio" id="PaymentType_0" form="form2" value="radio">
            BANK (ZENITH)</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>
            <input name="Direct_Payment" type="radio" id="PaymentType_1" form="form2" value="radio">
            DIRECT (CASH)
          </label></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>
        <label for="Teller No.">TELLER NO:</label>
        <input name="Teller No." type="text" id="Teller No." form="form2" size="40">
        <label for="Amount Paid">AMOUNT PAID:</label>
        <input name="Amount Paid" type="text" id="Amount Paid" form="form2" autocomplete="on" size="40">
  </p>
      <p>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" form ="form2" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset">
    </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: In another page you mean, the page that results after the submit, or at a different point of time in some other page?

Comment: yes the page that results after the submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this PHP code on `sendresult.php`

```
<?php

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
  echo "{$key}: {$value}<br />";
}

?>
```

Comment: Wao! Curtis W. this worked but one more thing - I need the displayed info to stay awhile for the user to print or copy and paste it and then click a button to move to the next page

Comment: this is the code i used in the php but it returns parse error //delay display before another code run
delay=10000; // 1000=1 sec